# Defining #if preprocessor condition in C

Tags: c, gcc

I wanted to define a compile time input validity checker for the library I am developing. So I thought maybe #define a function like #if preprocessor in C which is going to be compiled with GCC, something link this:

```
#define VALIDITY_CHECK(x) {#if (x)>10
                              #error "input out of range"
                              #endif}
```

But it doesn't work. So what is the proper way of writing such compile time validity checker?

Comment: It is not possible. You can’t have macro directives `#if` or `#error` in the value of a macro.

Comment: Maybe `assert()` is enough for you? Though it's not really a good idea for library code. The best thing to do is properly document the valid ranges of input values and declare UB when calling the function with anything outside, eg: `void foo(int x); /* does foo if 0 <= x < 10; otherwise it's UB */` like [`fopen()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3): "3. The argument mode points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @pmg, the OP want a test executed at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: @chmike my suggestion is to bypass the test altogether: neither at compile time (which is impossible), nor at run time (which may be inefficient).

Comment: @pmg it can be done at compile time by writing the #if #error ..., but not wrap it inside a macro function

Answer (score 2):

You can use a trick that provokes a compile time error if a condition is not met:

```
#define ASSERT(condition) (void)(sizeof (struct { int:-!(condition); }))

#define x1 23
#define x2 42

void f(void) {
    ASSERT(x1 < 31);
    ASSERT(x1 > 31);
    ASSERT(x2 < 31);
    ASSERT(x2 > 31);
}
```

It works by evaluating the condition by the `!`-operator as 1 for `false` and 0 for `true`. This number is used to declare an anonymous bit field of size -1 or 0, respectively, in a `struct`. The anonymous struct is just used for the `sizeof` operator, and the result is discarded as an unused expression.

Since a negative bit field size is not allowed, the compiler will output a diagnostic message, if the condition is not met.

If the condition is met, the compiler will happily optimize the unused expression away and generate no code for the line.

You could augment the `ASSERT()` by a comment behind it, if necessary. The diagnostic message will show it.

```
    ASSERT(x1 < 31); // Bla bla bla
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but brings up a lot of warnings even if the code is valid and if it's not valid, does not bring up a clear message

Comment: prepending (void) can avoid warning messages. like this: #define ASSERT(condition) (void)(sizeof (struct { int:-!(condition); }))

Comment: Good to know, thanks for pointing that out. What options do you use?

Comment: -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall

Comment: @Nixmd C11 _Static_assert is quite widely supported now. Could be a bit nicer to use than the bitfield-width trick (+it supports associated error messages).

Answer (score -1):

You can’t have macro directives in the value of a `#define`. This is because the # in a value is the "stringizing" operator and it must be followed by a macro argument.

In the `#define` value, you can thus have `#x` because `x` is the argument of `VALIDITY_CHECK`, but you can’t have `#if`, `#error`, or `#endif`.

You are forced to write the following code explicitly everywhere.

```c
#if (x)>10
#error "input out of range"
#endif
```

Comment: Like this `int x; scanf("%d", &x); #if (x)>10 #error "input out of range" #endif`? It does not work!

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work because #if tests are processed at compile time. I assumed the intent of the OP is to test the validity of x at compile time. Otherwise, his question wouldn’t make sense. It is nowhere stated that the OP expected that x is a runtime program variable. This is your assumption.